# main doesn't continue after call pthread_join function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm new to pthread and multithreading, i have written a code like that.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void *nfc_read(void *arg)
{
    int fd = -1;   
    int ret;
    uint8_t read_data[24];

    while(1){
        ret = read_block(fd, 8, read_data);
        if(!ret){
            return (void)read_data;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t my_thread;
    void  *returnValue;

    pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, nfc_read, NULL);
    pthread_join(my_thread, &returnValue);

    printf("NFC card value is : %s \n", (char)returnValue);

    printf("other process");

  return 0;
}
```

Until the return value from **nfc_read** function, as I will have other code I need to run and I don't want to block in main. How can i do that?

Comment: You put `pthread_join` at the point where you positively need the function to have completed.

Comment: If you don't want to block then don't call `pthread_join`. If you need the result of the thread then you will need to block or poll at some point. It's not clear exactly what behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if i remove **thread_join** function how can i get return value?

Comment: Also note that you're returning a local array which you cannot use after the function has finished

Comment: @SandaruwanFernando you need to have some kind of event handling mechanism in the main thread; so you'd notify it that the NFC read has now completed.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen do you have any event handling mechanism example for beginners?

Comment: @Scheff even for a "simple" thing like this, `volatile` is not sufficient: the threads might run on different CPUs, therefore requiring a memory barrier. The simplest thing to use might be pthread mutexes and condition variables.

Comment: @Scheff but in the code snippet, I don't see the need for synchronization other than `pthread_join()` at all. Just fixing the error of returning a "local variable" should produce working code. Maybe there's another problem not shown in OP's code.

Comment: Calling `pthread_create` immediately followed by `pthread_join` is just a very inefficient way to call a function.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Using `volatile` without atomic access might be not sufficient but with atomic access it should. Atomic access is probably much cheaper than a mutex. I found this (accepted) [answer for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9201088/7478597) (beside of the fact that I already did it this way by myself). I _assume_ that `std::atomic` is based on the same techniques like the functions in [Atomic Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic).

Comment: @Scheff: I was refering to the first part of your comment. Of course, an *atomic* type is sufficient. Whether this is the simplest thing is debatable. If it's really just used for a flag, of course it is more efficient than locking.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I agree and replace my first comment: The IMHO simplest kind of simple event handling between threads is using a variable (e.g. of type `int`) which is written in one thread and (cyclically) read in the other thread. Thereby, the write as well as read access have to be done using atomic operations (since C11 provided with [Atomic Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). Otherwise, the synchronization between threads might not be sufficient (as any CPU caching or similar internal effects may prevent this).

Comment: Is there any solution about that?

Comment: May be, I did understand your question wrong. If your intention is to have a "never-ending" main loop and a concurrently running "never-ending" read loop, then you should make familiar with [pthread_mutex](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init). A mutex can be used for mutual exclusion of concurrent data accesses. The actual overhanding of data can then be done using allocated buffers, lists, queues, and anything else what is usually available. However, every read/write access has to be guarded by a mutex lock to prevent that one thread disturbs the other in the _critical section_.

Comment: If I did understand your question wrong this might be caused by your misleading code sample. (I mean this as statement - not as offense.) May be, it's worth to edit it and expose the main loop somehow (even if it contains comments only). And, of course, `pthread_join()` is the function where two threads become one (the one which is calling it and the other for which the ID is provided). So, it has to be called after leaving the main loop.

Comment: the posted code is missing a necessary statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: in the function: `main()`, the parameters are not being used.  so should use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: before calling `read_block()` must have opened the input file, typically by `fopen()` or `open()`  And there is no function: `read_block()`  perhaps you meant `read()`

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 8, 24   'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: a thread cannot return a (useful) pointer to a character array.  However, it can return a  pointer to a 'status'.    The return type of a thread function is always `void*` so the function: `nfc_read()` should be returning a `void*` not a `void`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: the parameter to `nfc_read()` is not used, do the first line in the body of that function should be: `(void)arg;`

Comment: regarding the statement: `printf("NFC card value is : %s \n", (char)returnValue);`   The format specifier: `%s` is expecting a pointer to a NUL terminated array of char (char*).  Not (char)

Comment: what is this statement supposed to mean: `printf("other process");`?

Comment: the thread function: `nfc_read()` is returning the address of a local variable.  That variable will be 'out of scope' when the function exits.  So in `main()` that variable does not exist after the call to `pthread_join()`  Trying to print the contents of that local variable, in `main()`, is undefined behavior.  Suggest creating `read_data[]` via a call to `malloc()` or declaring it in `main()` and passing its address as the parameter to the thread function

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample where a read thread runs concurrently to the "main" thread which is doing other work (in this case, printing dots and sleeping).

To keep things simple, a simulated the reading from an input device with copying a constant string character by character. I guess, this is reasonable as the synchronization of threads is focused.

For the synchronization of threads, I used `atomic_bool` with `atomic_store()` and `atomic_load()` which are provided by the [Atomic Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) (since C11).

My sample application `test-concurrent-read.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* sampe input */
const char sampleInput[]
  = "This is sample input which is consumed as if it was read from"
    " a (very slow) external device.";

atomic_bool readDone = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);

void* threadRead(void *pArg)
{
  char **pPBuffer = (char**)pArg;
  size_t len = 0, size = 0;
  int c; const char *pRead;
  for (pRead = sampleInput; (c = *pRead++) > 0; sleep(1)) {
    if (len + 1 >= size) {
      if (!(*pPBuffer = realloc(*pPBuffer, (size + 64) * sizeof(char)))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR! Allocation failed!\n");
        break;
      }
      size += 64;
    }
    (*pPBuffer)[len++] = c; (*pPBuffer)[len] = '\0';
  }
  atomic_store(&readDone, 1);
  return NULL;
}

int main()
{
  /* start thread to read concurrently */
  printf("Starting thread...\n");
  pthread_t idThreadRead; /* thread ID for read thread */
  char *pBuffer = NULL; /* pointer to return buffer from thread */
  if (pthread_create(&idThreadRead, NULL, &threadRead, &pBuffer)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Failed to start read thread!\n");
    return -1;
  }
  /* start main loop */
  printf("Starting main loop...\n");
  do {
    putchar('.'); fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1);
  } while (!atomic_load(&readDone));
  putchar('\n');
  void *ret;
  pthread_join(idThreadRead, &ret);
  /* after sync */
  printf("\nReceived: '%s'\n", pBuffer ? pBuffer : "<NULL>");
  free(pBuffer);
  /* done */
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled and tested with gcc in cygwin on Windows 10 (64 bit):

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -pthread -o test-concurrent-read test-concurrent-read.c

$ ./test-concurrent-read
Starting thread...
Starting main loop...
.............................................................................................

Received: 'This is sample input which is consumed as if it was read from a (very slow) external device.'

$
```

I guess, it is worth to mention why there is no mutex guarding for `pBuffer` which is used in `main()` as well as in `threadRead()`.

1. `pBuffer` is initialized in `main()` *before* `pthread_create()` is called.
2. While `thread_read()` is running, `pBuffer` is used by it exclusively (via its passed address in `pPBuffer`).
3. It is accessed in `main()` again but *not before* `pthread_join()` which grants that `threadRead()` has ended.

I tried to find a reference by google to confirm that this procedure is well-defined and reasonable. The best, I could find was [SO: pthread_create(3) and memory synchronization guarantee in SMP architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347856/pthread-create3-and-memory-synchronization-guarantee-in-smp-architectures) which cites [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 - 4.12 Memory Synchronization](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12).